# Nuget versioning and claims about "forward compatibility"

Tags: c#, nuget

How should I read the dependency definitions of nuget packages?

E.g. we have two dependencies:

- [dotnetzip 1.1.13](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/1.13.0#dependencies-body-tab)
- [System.DirectoryServices 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices/7.0.0#dependencies-body-tab)

Both have `System.Security.Permissions` dependency:

- dotnetzip pulls in version **(>= 4.5.0 && < 5.0.0)**
- System.DrectoryServices pulls in version (>= 7.0.0)

compiler complains about version conflicts.

So I upgrade dotnetzip to 1.16.0, which pulls in System.Security.Permissions **(>= 4.7.0)**

So compiler is happy. But now I wonder, how does this work? How can the owner of dotnetzip predict the future? What if newer versions of System.Security.Permissions have breaking interface, as they should be allowed to have if they bumped their major version several times in this case?

And how can we be sure that dotnetzip will keep working correctly in all cases, with a much newer version of System.Security.Permissions?

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: dotnetzip probably should not claim it works with System.Security.Permissions >= 4.7.0, but should have kept their "<" claim to whatever version of System.Security.Permissions they tested their library with. But that takes effort. And time. In the meanwhile, there are other libraries claiming compatibility with whatever version of System.Security.Permissions you got. So what do you think libraries are going to do?

Comment: Very odd.  A major version bump is by definition (of semantic versioning) a potentially breaking change.  So you can't (safely, automatically) take a new major version you haven't agreed to.  Claiming >= 4.7.0 should *not* accept 5.0.0.  How else would you protect yourself from breaking changes if not to disallow a newer major version?  I would say that to claim >= 4.7.0, taken to mean that any greater major version is permissible, is an error.  >= 4.7.0 should mean 4.x.y where x >= 7.

Comment: Please check if you made a typo: 1.1.6? Maybe [1.16.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/1.16.0#dependencies-body-tab)?

Comment: @Wyck It depends. At least the System assemblies are typically forward compatible even across major versions. The designers are very restrictive with breaking changes in those.

Comment: @Sinatr woops, fixed that.